# Out of universe, why was Wesley Crusher included in Star Trek: Nemesis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-nemesis

Wesley Crusher is one of the most reviled *Star Trek* characters of all time (or at least when he was first introduced). Disregarding this, an important part of the character's arc is when he leaves Starfleet behind to become a Traveler. Despite this, he appears in *Star Trek: Nemesis*. In-universe he apparently gave up being a Traveler and re-joined Star fleet under the command of the new Captain Riker. Why was this decision made by the writers? From a creative standpoint, it totally destroys Wesley's arc for the sake of a cameo. From a different (economic?) standpoint, that character was one of the most hated in *Star Trek* history, so why would he be included a film?

Comment: Perhaps because the people who didn't like Wesley were a small (but extremely vocal) minority who're gonna go see the film anyway and those that did like him are happy to see him in the film? http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/7.218904-Wil-Wheaton-Proves-That-People-Liked-Wesley-Crusher

Comment: The Traveler was able to take humanoid form to interact with humans.  Why would anyone assume that Wesley, living as a Traveler, would not be able to do the same, especially since that form was his original form?  Also, in the script he did have more to do, but it ended up on the cutting room floor.

Comment: It's also possible they like Will Wheaton as a person even though they didn't like Wesley but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Servitor - or the film was made at roughly the same time Wil Wheaton was starting to become an Internet personality and the producers wanted to cash in on that...

Comment: I think the question of "why destroy his arc for the sake of a cameo" part of this question is more important and interesting than "Why have him appear despite his character being disliked"...

Comment: Wheaton talked about it in his blog back in 2001:  http://www.wilwheaton.net/mt/archives/2001/11/13/  Basically during a taping of a Star Trek episode of "The Weakest Link", LeVar Burton suggested he should be in it, and decided to suggest it to the producers, who then approved a cameo and contacted Wheaton's agent.